# Stackable traits in Python

Tags: python

I am implementing a hierarchy of classes in Python. The common base class exposes a few methods like an interface, there are a few abstract classes that should not be instantiated directly and each of the concrete subclasses can mixin a few of the abstract classes and provide additional behaviour. For example, the following code is a simple example of what I started from:

```py
class BaseEntity(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def f(self) -> List[str]:
        pass

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def g(self) -> int:
        pass


class AbstractEntity1(BaseEntity, ABC):  # this should not be instantiable
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def f(self) -> List[str]:
        return ["a", "b"]

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def g(self) -> int:
        return 10


class AbstractEntity2(BaseEntity, ABC):  # this should not be instantiable
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def f(self) -> List[str]:
        return ["x"]

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def g(self) -> int:
        return 3


class FinalEntity(AbstractEntity1, AbstractEntity2, BaseEntity):

    @property
    def f(self) -> List[str]:
        return ["C"]

    @property
    def g(self) -> int:
        return 10
```

I would like `FinalEntity` and all other concrete entities to behave as follows: when I call `final_entity.f()`, it should return ["a", "b", "x", "C"] (so the equivalent of calling the `+` operator on each of the mixins and the class itself); similarly, when I call `final_entity.g()`, it should return `10 + 3 + 10` (i.e. calling the `+` operator on each of the mixins and the class itself). The functions are obviously just an example and it won't always be `+`, so it will have to be defined for each of the functions.

What is the best pythonic way to approach this problem?

Comment: decorators can be useful. . . And then they can create confusion. You seem to have found a case when there is "over decoration".

Comment: also the code is missing `from abc import ABC, abstractmethod` since it is not built-in but an imported decorator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congratulations! You've discovered when *not* to use inheritance. Inheritance is a very specific tool in a programmer's toolbelt that solves a very specific problem, but there are lots of poor tutorials and poor instructors out there that try to hammer *every* nail in the software development world with subclasses.

What you have is called a *list*, not a series of superclasses. If you want `FinalEntity` to *have* a bunch of traits, then that's a *has-a* relationship. We model *has-a* relationships with *composition*, not *inheritance*.

That is, rather than having `FinalEntity` *inherit* from all of its traits, we have it *contain* them.

```
class Trait1:
    def f(self):
        return ["a", "b"]

class Trait2:
    def f(self):
        return ["x"]

class Trait3:
    def f(self):
        return ["C"]
```

Then your `FinalEntity` can simply be

```
class FinalEntity:

    def __init__(self, traits):
        self.traits = traits

    def f(self):
        return [value for trait in self.traits for value in trait.f()]
```

As a bonus, this is *way* easier to write tests for. Your proposed `FinalEntity` is *tightly coupled* to its parents, so you wouldn't be able to test it with different traits without mocking. But *this* `FinalEntity` has a constructor that directly plugs-and-plays different traits for free.

---

Note that, if you *really* want to use inheritance, you just need to call `super` in the subclasses, and Python's default method resolution order will take it the rest of the way.

```
class BaseEntity:
    def f(self):
        return []

class AbstractEntity1(BaseEntity):
    def f(self):
        return super.f() + ["a", "b"]

class AbstractEntity2(BaseEntity):
    @abstractmethod
    def f(self):
        return super.f() + ["x"]

class FinalEntity(AbstractEntity1, AbstractEntity2):
    def f(self):
        return super.f() + ["C"]
```

But, again, this is going to result in more brittle code that's harder to test.

---

For what it's worth, the feature you're looking for is called *method combinations*. This isn't a feature available in Python, but some languages, most notably Common Lisp, do support this out of the box. The equivalent to your code in Common Lisp would be

```
(defclass base () ())
(defclass abstract1 (base) ())
(defclass abstract2 (base) ())
(defclass final (abstract1 abstract2) ())

(defgeneric f (value)
  (:method-combination append :most-specific-last))

(defmethod f append ((value abstract1))
  (list "a" "b"))

(defmethod f append ((value abstract2))
  (list "x"))

(defmethod f append ((value final))
  (list "C"))

(let ((instance (make-instance 'final)))
  (format t "~A~%" (f instance))) ;; Prints ("a" "b" "x" "C")
```

But, again, that's not available in Python without a *lot* of clever reflection tricks.